# Using Rational Function Tester to test Microsoft Office Applications

Tags: rft

I am new to IBM Rational Functional Tester.  Does anyone know if this tool supports the testing of Microsoft Office Applications?  Do I need to install any special software, plugins, tools etc to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow..
RFT supports  applications created with .Net/WPF/Win among others and  most likely MS office might be using one of them so it should work. The only problem which I anticipate is if  the office uses some customized controls in those cases RFT might identify the controls as generic control. But I would try and see if how does it record on the controls (just click a few controls and look at the object map to find out what is the value of Domain property under the adminstrative Tab of the object map for one of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never,

I tried IBM Functional Test 8.6.0.5 along with Microsoft Office 2013, and the tester did not manage to work with Word. While trying to record an automated test script, none of the clicks inside word were captured.